# How to exclude gatsby-created pages from being indexed?

Tags: gatsby, sitemap

#### Context

[Gatsby](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/), the headless CMS marvel, alongside [`gatsby-plugin-advanced-sitemap`](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/packages/gatsby-plugin-advanced-sitemap/) makes generating a robust `sitemap.xml` file a breeze.

The plugin supports excluding pages with either by slug or with clever regular expression.

However in my case, I have 2 collections of User-Generated Content pages:

- the collection A, with pages that need to be hosted, **and indexed**,
- the collection B, with pages that need to be hosted, **but NOT indexed**.

The B collection has not a slug pattern making them identifiable with a regular expression.

#### Question

How to exclude the collection B from indexation?

Comment: Example slugs would help answer this question. Please provide examples. Also post your code of your `gatsby-plugin-advanced-sitemap` inside your `gatsby-config.js`.

Answer (score 5):

Files that you don't include (or exclude) in your `sitemap.xml` can be indexed too if their `robotx.txt` allows Google's robots with an `index` attribute, or if the links from other pages to the page have a `follow` attribute.

Regarding your question, the plugin allows you to add a `exclude` array of pages that won't be added in your `sitemap.xml` despite being retrieved by your query. So, in your `gatsby-config.js`:

```
{
      resolve: `gatsby-plugin-advanced-sitemap`,
      options: {
        query: `{}`, // your query
        mapping: {}, // add if needed
        exclude: [
          `/dev-404-page`,
          `/404`,
          `/404.html`,
          `/offline-plugin-app-shell-fallback`,
          `/terms-and-conditions`,
          `/terms-of-use`,
          `/cookie-policy`,
          `/privacy-policy`,
          /(\/)?hash-\S*/,
        ],
        createLinkInHead: true,
        addUncaughtPages: true,
        additionalSitemaps: [], // add if needed
      },
    },
```

Ideally, your excluded pages may follow a regular expression way to be excluded automatically when generated. However, if don't, as the code above shows, you can add manually. In this case, nor `/terms-of-use`, `/cookie-policy`, or `/privacy-policy` won't be added in your `sitemap.xml`.